# ActiveDirectory FolderRedirection and iTunes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, itunes, active-directory, folder-redirection

today I had a tricky problem with iTunes 12 not synchronizing with outlook.

Our ActiveDirectory has a folderRedirection for the users AppData as well as every other user directory usualy found in c:\users\%username% to a network share.

As long as the AppData redirection was active iTunes refused to connect to outlook with a "Microsoft outlook is not installed" message.

Does anybody have an idea why this is?

thx
moe

Comment: iTunes might be just be hardcoded to look for certain Outlook files contained within `%appdata%` at the default `C:\Users\user` path. Can you exclude certain folders/files from Folder Redirection?

Comment: FolderRedirection only allows the full AppData directory to be redirected. Sadly there is no exclusion...

Comment: With your AppData redirection enabled, trying copying the contents of the redirected `\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` folder to the local hard drive at `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` and report what happens.